# Customizing Wagtail Admin List View for Page Model: Adding Filters

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin, wagtail-snippet

I am working with Wagtail CMS and need to customize the list view in the admin interface for Page models. Specifically, I want to add filtering capabilities for certain properties of the Page model, such as "status" and "price". However, Wagtail's standard admin interface doesn't seem to provide a straightforward way to achieve this for Page models, as it does for other Django models with ModelAdmin. I'm looking for guidance or a solution to implement this functionality.

I have looked through the Wagtail documentation to find information on customizing the admin list view for Page models but was unable to find specific guidance or examples that match my requirements. My search did not yield results that could help in implementing the particular customizations I am seeking.